# Solubitity of FeS

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, equilibrium, solubility

I have some questions related to a problem of multiple equilibria and solubility. I have to calculate the solubility of FeS in pure water considering that the second stage of hydrolisis of $\ce{S^2-}$, producing $\ce{H2S}$, can not be neglected.

For this problem the book that I was consulting gives me the values of the dissociation constants for $\ce{H2S}$ ($K_\mathrm{a1} = \pu{1.0e-7}$ and $K_\mathrm{a2} = \pu{1.2e-13}$) and the solubility product of $\ce{FeS}$ ($K_\mathrm{sp} = \pu{8e-9}$). I proposed the following reactions:
\begin{align}
\ce{FeS &<=> Fe^2+ + S^2-}\tag{R1}\\
\ce{H2S + H2O &<=> HS- + H3O+}\tag{R2}\\
\ce{HS- + H2O &<=> S^2- + H3O+}\tag{R3}\\
\ce{2H2O &<=> OH- + H3O+}\tag{R4}
\end{align}
From these ones I got the mass and charge balance equations:
\begin{align}
[\ce{Fe^2+}] &= [\ce{HS-}] + [\ce{S^2-}] + [\ce{H2S}]\tag{1}\\
2[\ce{Fe^2+}] + [\ce{H3O+}] &= 2[\ce{S^2-}] + [\ce{HS-}] + [\ce{OH-}]\tag{2}
\end{align}
I also get other equations from the equilibrium of the acid in the two stages of its dissociation:
\begin{align}
K_\mathrm{a1} &= \frac{[\ce{HS-}][\ce{H3O+}]}{[\ce{H2S}]}\tag{3}\\
K_\mathrm{a1} &= \frac{[\ce{S^2-}][\ce{H3O+}]}{[\ce{HS-}]}\tag{4}
\end{align}
The solubility product of salt and the ionic product of water:
\begin{align}
K_\mathrm{sp} &= [\ce{Fe^2+}][\ce{S^2-}]\tag{5}\\
K_\mathrm{w} &= [\ce{H3O+}][\ce{OH-}]\tag{6}
\end{align}
I have six equation in total. So my doubt is: how to simplify these equations? Well, what relation could I get from the mass or charge balance equation in order to simplify the process of resolution?

In my book the answer is $\pu{4e-7}$, but I don't get the necessary relation to resolve all of this problem.

I would really appreciate some advice about it.

Comment: This exercise isn't particularly good. Ka2 is way off, and isn't appropriate to describe protonation of sulfur bound to iron. Also check out http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0016703706001992